# Making an installer for the app with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition integrating VC++ 2015 Environment in it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, windows-installer, installation

I have no problems creating installer for my app using free Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and a [plugin for it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects), however I have absolutely no luck integrating latest Visual C++ Runtime Environment into installer.

I know the recommended way is to include MSM module, which I did, but still no luck: when deployed on some machine, the app got installed properly, but the damn Runtime Environment is not.

I am about to drop the whole Visual Studio thing and go back to MinGW, since I use Qt. I like it, but the official version is 32-bit only which was the single reason to try Visual Studio.

Any solutions?

Comment: "Not working" isn't the best description of your problem. We need a lot more details to be able to tell anything.

Comment: I mean installer installs the app in question, but doesn't install the VC++ runtime. And it is required to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the setup in solution explorer and select Properties, then Prerequisites, then check the Create setup program to install prerequisites. That shows a list of prerequisites that includes the VC 14 C++ runtimes (VS 2015). You'll end up with a setup.exe that will install the marked prerequisites and then install your MSI.

Comment: A bit late, since I already fell back to MinGW and BitRock InstallBuilder. However, I'll try your solution during the next release.